# Is it possible to access a remote database if I have db username,password and host?

Tags: php, mysql

I found the above mentioned database credentials commented out in my college's website and I want to know if its possible to access the database remotely with only this much info.

The comment was of the format

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxx","xxxx","xxxxx");
```

I tried `mysql -u USERNAME -h HOST db_name -p` and then password on the prompt but it gets stuck there and I have to abort the command. How do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: it doesn't work. I tried mysql -u USERNAME -h HOST db_name -p and then password on the prompt but it gets stuck their and I have to abort the command

Comment: Firewalls are likely at play here.

Comment: Okay thanks. It makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of other factors impacting your ability to connect.

- The network likely has firewalls preventing access from the public internet and/or unauthorized internal users.
- The MySQL user may be limited to connecting from specific IP addresses, ranges, or just locally.
- The MySQL server may not be configured to listen to external IPs.

It's unlikely you'll be able to connect, and attempting to do so when you're not an authorized user may be a violation of your college's Acceptable Use Policy. If you have a *legitimate* need for this, contact the IT department for access.

Answer (score -3):

Why do you want to access the college Database? Well, I suggest you don't except you have the exclusive right to do so. On the condition that you have the right to access, then it is very possible to access remote database with correct login credential. You might use: 
$connection = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database_name');
if you know the public IP address of the server, you might replace the localhost with it if the above does not work.